# Use of XmlSchemaSet with XmlPreloadedResolver for XDocument validation

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to validate a manually built `XDocument` with `XmlSchemaSet`.
Also, I want to make use of `XmlPreloadedResolver` so I can retrieve a local copy of the schemas and avoid web access.

I add the content of the [root schema](http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:enids="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/firma" 
xmlns:enidocmeta="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/metadatos" 
xmlns:enifile="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/contenido" 
xmlns:enidoc="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e" 
targetNamespace="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="es">XSD DOCUMENTO ENI (v1.0)</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/metadatos" schemaLocation="metadatosDocumentoEni.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/firma" schemaLocation="firmasEni.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/contenido" schemaLocation="contenidoDocumentoEni.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="documento" type="enidoc:TipoDocumento">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="es">El elemento "documento" podrá aparecer como elemento raíz de un documento XML objeto de intercambio o como elemento no raíz (elemento hijo).</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="TipoDocumento">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="enifile:contenido"/>
            <xsd:element ref="enidocmeta:metadatos"/>
            <xsd:element ref="enids:firmas" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="es">La firma es obligatoria para el documento administrativo electrónico y para todo aquel documento electrónico susceptible de ser incorporado en un expediente electrónico.</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Id" type="xsd:ID" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

So I build a `XmlPreloadedResolver` for all transitive dependencies, pointing to local copies of the remote xsds:

```
var resolver = new XmlPreloadedResolver();
resolver.add(
"http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/contenido", 
File.ReadAllBytes("local/path/to/contenidoDocumentoEni.xsd"));
...
```

Then I create a `SchemaSet` including the root schema:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings {
                XmlResolver = resolver,
                DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
            };

var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();


using (var fs = new FileStream("./local/path/to/documentoEni.xsd", FileMode.Open))
using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(fs, settings))
{
    schemaSet.Add(_enidoc.NamespaceName, xr);
}
schemaSet.Compile();
```

I am getting a `XmlSchemaValidationException: the element http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/contenido:contenido is not declared`.

That element is defined in the first dependency, so I guess that I'm not properly creating the `XmlPreloadedResolver` or the `XmlSchemaSet`.

I assume the schemas are right because they are being used by a myriad of applications.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].   Namespace declarations aren't sufficient; you need `xs:import`s too, plus a myriad of other things could be wrong -- really need to post a MCVE so we don't have to start guessing.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are completely  right. The thing is that I am assuming that the schemas are right, because they are in use by many applications (added this assumption to the question text). I suspect the problem is in my code and that's why I tried to provide the minimum (hoping sufficient) information. Please tell my if it is ok now. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure the XmlPreloadedResolver helps with the schema loading, as far as I can see in your main schema all `schemaLocation` URIs are relative URIs so I would assume when you do the `schemaSet.Add("http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e", "mainSchema.xsd")` with a local file system location that all referenced schemas are loaded anyway from the local file system, without setting up any particular resolver. The only problem is that one schema references a W3C schema with an absolute URI http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd.

Comment: XML file sample that validates XSD file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `XmlSchemaSet` needs all locally referenced schemas be added to the set, or `XmlPreloadedResolver` does not resolve to the provided `URIs`.

I have managed to get it working by manually adding the schemas to the `XmlSchemaSet` this way:

```
public static XmlSchemaSet SchemaSet() {

    XNamespace enidoc =
        "http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e";
    XNamespace enidocMeta =
        "http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/metadatos";
    XNamespace enids = "http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/firma";
    XNamespace enifile =
        "http://administracionelectronica.gob.es/ENI/XSD/v1.0/documento-e/contenido";
    XNamespace ds = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";

    var namespaces =
        new Dictionary < XNamespace, string > { 
            { enidoc, "./Schemas/Eni/documentoEni.xsd"}, 
            { enidocMeta, "./Schemas/Eni/metadatosDocumentoEni.xsd"}, 
            { enids, "./Schemas/Eni/firmasEni.xsd"}, 
            { enifile, "./Schemas/Eni/contenidoDocumentoEni.xsd" }, 
            { ds, "./Schemas/Eni/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" }
    };

    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();

    foreach(var ns in namespaces) {
        using(var fs = new FileStream(ns.Value, FileMode.Open))
        using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(fs)) {
            schemaSet.Add(ns.Key.NamespaceName, xr);
        }
    }

    schemaSet.Compile();
    return schemaSet;
}
```